# Complement a POSIX Extended Regular Expression

Tags: code-golf, regular-expression

Given a [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) [Extended Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended) as input, output its complement (also a POSIX ERE). If the given regular expression matches a string, its complement should not match it, and the regex: `(regex given)|(complement)` should match any string. In other words, negate the regex.

The regex for format input and for output, POSIX ERE, is basically regex without character classes, lookarounds, backreferences, etc. You can assume that we only care about ASCII characters. Also, assume that character classes do not contain `-` for use as ranges (no `[a-d]` as input; instead, the input would be `[abcd]`). Further assume that `?` and `+`  and `{}` will not be used in the input as metacharacters. `x?` will be shown with `x|` and `x+` by `xx*` where x is an arbitrary regular expression. The variations of `{m,n}` will be similarly written out (e.g.: instead of `x{1,4}`, you'll get `x|xx|xxx|xxxx`).

Sample Input:

```
^([helo][world])([helo][world])*$
```

Possible Output (Thanks [Peter Taylor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14223416#14223416)):

```
^(([helo]([world][helo])*)?$|([helo][world])*[^helo]|[helo]([world][helo])*[^wo‌​rld])
```

Please post a few sample Input/Outputs

Comment: The string `ao` is neither matched by the input nor the given output. A possible output would be `^(|(..)*.|(..)*[^helo].(..)*|(..)*.[^world](..)*)$` (assuming `.` matches all characters).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks, I decided to go with Peter Taylor's version instead.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no way to complement the empty pattern that matches everything.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek See http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18393/9498 . Example: `.^` It's not possible for a character to be before the start of a string.

Comment: Oh "complement", not "compliment"... I was going to answer something on the lines of "Nice word boundaries!"

Comment: I feel like this will be too hard unless you give a simpler regex grammar than POSIX ERE.

Comment: @PeterOlson What do you suggest then? Also, next time, try to bring this up in the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/?cb=1).

Comment: I'd suggest a simple grammar that can be described in a few lines. You could use the [formal definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition) of a regular expression, which only uses concatenation (`RS`), alternation (`R|S`), and Kleene star (`R*`).

Comment: @PeterOlson That looks good, but I would like to include `.`. Would that make it too difficult?

Comment: I don't think that would make it much harder

Comment: @PeterOlson I had another thought; anything in this POSIX ERE can be replaced with something else to make it part of the formal definition. Instead of using the formal definition, I say use POSIX ERE, but restrict input as follows: no ranges in character classes; no character class negations; no use of `?` or `+`; `()` will only be used when necessary. Output can use any of those.

Comment: If you include `.`, what will be the complement of e.g. `AB.D`?

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin Note I said assume that we are using ASCII. This means that `.` is equivalent to `[x-~]` where the `x` is the null character (ASCII 0). Basically, it is possible to translate POSIX ERE into the formal definition of regular expressions. I'm not sure what the complement would be; I'm working on it.

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin A complement of your regular expression is `^([A][B].[^D]|[A][B].$|[A][B]$|[A][^B]|[A]$|[^A])*$`. I also found a tool for testing POSIX ERE expressions: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/golang/index.html

Comment: There's an answer here which describes how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14817545/1396205

Comment: Hmm had more of a look at this. It's possible, but crazy tedious. You need to parse the regexp into an NFA (eg Thompson's algorithm), convert the NFA to a DFA (powerset construction), complete the DFA, find the complement, then convert the DFA to a RE (eg Brzozowski's method). ie slightly harder than writing a complete RE engine! I'd expect a golfed version would need to use library functions for each step.

Comment: @mbomb007 I think that was meant to be "complement", not "compliment"... At any rate, I didn't answer or comment on this question until now... So I'm a little confused, why refer to me...?

Comment: [Not quite a duplicate](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3130/62131) because it allows regex syntaxes other than ERE, which actually makes a very large difference here.

Comment: @WallyWest [yeah you did...](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24352/complement-a-posix-extended-regular-expression#comment51205_24352)

Comment: @Justin Can we assume that every input regex will start with `^` and end with `$` (i.e. no "fuzzy" matching)? If so, I think I will have a solution soon.

Comment: Though honestly, supporting printable ASCII is going to be rough, if meta-characters have to be included in the alphabet.

Comment: @mbomb007 TBH, it's been so long since I posted this challenge that I'm unsure what is reasonable. I can revisit this and carefully revise it to make it simpler (stuff like only printable ascii or something). Also, is we have a regex `regex`, if it doesn't start with `^`, isn't it exactly equivalent to `^.*regex`? I don't know what I originally intended; it will take some work to figure that out

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I guess that's fine. I guess it depends what you want the challenge to be. Supporting escaped meta-characters is honestly going to be a challenge in itself if they are part of the alphabet. If what you really want is for the complementing the regex to be the entirety of the challenge, maybe supporting the characters `[A-Za-z0-9]` plus spaces is enough. Idk. If that was enough, I could (probably) have an answer today.

Comment: The parts I haven't finished yet are replacing character classes `[abc]` with `(a|b|c)` so that I can work with them, and supporting (certain) escaped meta-chars. I think I get can printable ASCII to work, but it'll just take a while.

Comment: Also, golfing will take a long time. The code I have so far is basically 30KB.

Comment: @mbomb007 write an automatic golfer for it? (Or just do a size-optimization compile)

Comment: @Rogem I just haven't been working on this lately. My previous comment still stands, as I'm not finished with supporting all of the necessary characters yet. As I said, if all I need was to support `[A-Za-z0-9]`, I'd probably have submitted an answer already.

Answer (score 22):

## JavaScript, 1563 bytes

```js
m=>`^${((l,n={s:{[e(l[0])]:""}})=>((t=s=>n[x=e(s)]=n[x]||(n[x]={},r.reduce(((r,o,c)=>(c=l[2](s)(o),t(c),r[x=e(c)]=(r[x]||"[]")[$](0,-1)+("\\"==o||"]"==o?"\\":"")+o+"]",l[1](s)||(r.e=""),r)),{})))(l[0]),(g=Object.keys)(n)[h]((e=>"s"!=e&&(c=n[e],d=c[e],delete c[e],delete n[e],g(n)[h]((l=>(s=n[l][e])!={}.x&&delete n[l][e]&&g(c)[h]((e=>(o=s+(d?`(${d})*`:"")+c[e],n[l][e]=n[l][e]!={}.x?`(${n[l][e]}|${o})`:o)))))))),n.s.e||"[]"))((a=e=>e===e+""?e?[0,e=>1==e,l=>t=>[t==e?1:2,2,2][l]]:[0,e=>!e,e=>e=>1]:[([e])=>[0,l=>!l||l.some((l=>e[1](l))),t=>r=>l((t||[e[0]]).flatMap((l=>[x=e[2](l)(r),...e[1](x)?[e[0]]:[]])))],e=>[e[h]((e=>e[0])),l=>l.some(((l,t)=>e[t][1](l))),l=>t=>l[h](((l,r)=>e[r][2](l)(t)))],([e,t])=>[[e[0],e[1](e[0])?[t[0]]:[]],e=>e[1].some((e=>t[1](e))),r=>s=>[x=e[2](r[0])(s),l([...e[1](x)?[t[0]]:[],...r[1][h]((e=>t[2](e)(s)))])]],l=>[0,e=>1==e,l=>t=>[e[1].includes(t)?1:2,2,2][l]]][e[0]](e[1][h](a)))((f=e=>e.length?e.reduce(((e,l)=>[2,[e,l]])):"")(m[$="slice"](1,-1).split(/(\\.|[^\\])/).filter((e=>e)).reverse(e=JSON.stringify,l=l=>[...new Set(l[h](e))].sort()[h](JSON.parse),r=[...Array(95)][h](((e,l)=>String.fromCharCode(l+32))),h="map")[u="reduceRight"](p=(e,l,t,s)=>e&&{[l]:t=>[...e,l[$](-1)],".":l=>[...e,[3,r]],"*":l=>e.concat([[0,[e.pop()]]]),"[":l=>[...e,((e,l)=>[3,e?r.filter((e=>!l.includes(e))):l])(n="^"==s[t-1],s.splice(s.lastIndexOf("]"),s.length)[$](1,-n||{}.x)[h]((e=>e[$](-1))))],")":l=>(i=e,0),"(":l=>[...e,(s[u](p,[]),[1,i.reduce((([e,...l],t)=>1==t?[[],e,...l]:[[...e,t],...l]),[[]])[h](f)])],"|":l=>[...e,1]}[s.pop()](),[]))))}$`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVRNb@M2EP0rMWEYw5jh2gl6qAraKPbUAm2AzZFmYFWmP7a0ZJBMNoHl354@UnLsrXSQOJw3b97MkN/L1zJUfneId3Wzsh@vpb/Z/lY1dWicla7ZEH3s1Wz5PDwSOVGrYyiO2pLTE8NNwdjpxNWMKKqgZrV@U5YCNwp/pm0pfdTxJLz0dvVSWSLyohFVglTK6XsDb2q4iFRx4TO8Apx8xjNtGNdDQxNxN@VjYosFU6rBhknfeVojBT5uxrAIp6cpHni9tAp24TkXxxPnvMtX0EY9/vPdVlH@a9/BXHO9NURWzVhgA2VHI6RVa2vESlX5Y52N9ub6P29vzlAHJQEQZ2DmA4iVb6PRp2s2j0YbqDozUaPCmFbzJQ2PqxO/XWYFmaH3P4fromXH3nJqh8fmxJdFw/tH1DJI25eKE5UKFFYpZceMze1cTwQMU6wFUo1qpiP@59PiXuA1CGuKzmdgRYbOprBQUgPnSUINXNs6GZq9zXptKrNL3Ajn1cyh@22rLSpsuFy7Mv5VHrJn6mfqsePkuZBSZugbn3fOhQaAc5N4Yenrk7YQG/AzJ@Yu8rQRzSd1J8ZlEPZ93vemZ4s5LESImGVkPpHZc/i5jucEsmhs9FxYxeyWSCAuXFT4hMR8CUf6Wss5VBLoYTwLiQlkEwLJcDC5XND/tSNz7@rKvaxsQOI/tcZ0hSLbhy3TKNM691g6W2/idm4vZwtBk9p7AeEu1TaNFu31ULHgdpVlhqbpJMlwcLtIX2ixkK1@XiwM/4LO7Vy0vusB54j6an2wWP759Pi3DNHv6s1u/S62iu3LA46bSoIgurY/bp5spNwNQFMtfaQ88Rl7KBEolTN5/@59@U6//sK7QvVJP@Xwcu2b/ddt6b/iLiI3frhPM65fFOs0ftttthEqDirBRBQh9X00OqJYReyywUa6MiDTCCZZ4c5m/SA8usBus81KXHJVGUmjJ9rKQ3MgNAmXBNNXoM@iPgg799c1GrhL29K0FA7TUSv2jKsp6Hg3NSLkQqM1QboyxD/qlX17XBPuKo69rn/5fkNX6rZNp51fjkEnIk8y4zkl2mFuJsiQrjMM@gUVERqp66nYXcYBUwAPZ/LpwczFucaU9sZCd/BoujXA6Tgm@nUaV8HaK5KpOenQ14h44sJzGi4/OLFn0lvrGqN/NN6tUISfl7dDXEwf/wE)

### Input/Output Examples

The challenge was to golf the source, not the output ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

```
Input: ^([helo][world])([helo][world])*$
Output: ^(((((((((|[ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcdfgijkmnpqrstuvwxyz{|}~]([ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~])*)|[ehlo])|[ehlo][ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcefghijkmnpqstuvxyz{|}~]([ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~])*)|[ehlo][dlorw][ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcdfgijkmnpqrstuvwxyz{|}~]([ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~])*)|[ehlo][dlorw][ehlo])|[ehlo][dlorw][ehlo][ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcefghijkmnpqstuvxyz{|}~]([ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~])*)|[ehlo][dlorw][ehlo][dlorw][ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcdfgijkmnpqrstuvwxyz{|}~]([ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~])*)|[ehlo][dlorw][ehlo][dlorw][ehlo](|[ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcefghijkmnpqstuvxyz{|}~]([ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~])*))|[ehlo][dlorw][ehlo][dlorw][ehlo][dlorw]([ehlo][dlorw])*([ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcdfgijkmnpqrstuvwxyz{|}~]([ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~])*|[ehlo](|[ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcefghijkmnpqstuvxyz{|}~]([ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~])*)))$

Input: ^.*$
Output: ^[]$ # Empty character set matches nothing

Input: ^[]$
Output: ^(|[ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~]([ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~])*)$

Input: ^(|[ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~]([ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~])*)$
Output: ^[]$
```

### <s>Ungolfed</s> Less Golfed

```js
let input = "^([helo][world])([helo][world])*$"

const star = 0
const union = 1
const concat = 2
const group = 3
const charset = [...Array(95)].map((_, i) => String.fromCharCode(i + 32));

input = `.*${input}.*`.replace(/\.\*\^|\$\.\*/g, "");

const makeConcat = x => x.length ? x.reduce((a, b) => [concat, [a, b]]) : "";

const regex = makeConcat(input
  .split(/(\\.|[^\\])/)
  .filter(x => x)
  .reverse()
  .reduceRight(_parseRegex = (acc, char, i, arr) => (
    acc && {
      [char]: _ => [...acc, char.slice(-1)],
      ".": _ => [...acc, [group, charset]],
      "*": _ => acc.concat([[star, [acc.pop()]]]),
      "[": _ => [...acc, ((i, a) =>
        [group, i ? charset.filter(x => !a.includes(x)) : a]
      )(
        invert = arr[i - 1] == "^",
        arr
          .splice(arr.lastIndexOf("]"), arr.length)
          .slice(1, -invert || {}.x)
          .map(x => x.slice(-1))
      )],
      ")": _ => (result = acc, null),
      "(": _ => [...acc, (
        arr.reduceRight(_parseRegex, []),
        [union, result.reduce(([a, ...b], char) => (
          char == union ? [[], a, ...b] : [[...a, char], ...b]
        ), [[]]).map(makeConcat)]
      )],
      "|": _ => [...acc, union],
    }[arr.pop()]()
  ), []))

const str = JSON.stringify;
const set = x => [...new Set(x.map(str))].sort().map(JSON.parse)

const initial = 0;
const accept = 1;
const next = 2;

const dfa = (regexToDfa = re =>
  re === re + ""
    ? re
      ? [0, x => x == 1, x => c => [c == re ? 1 : 2, 2, 2][x]]
      : [0, x => !x, x => c => 1]
    : [
      // star
      ([sub]) => [
        0,
        state => !state || state.some(substate => sub[accept](substate)),
        state => char => set((state || [sub[initial]]).flatMap(substate => [
          x = sub[next](substate)(char),
          ...sub[accept](x) ? [sub[initial]] : []
        ]))
      ],
      // union
      subs => [
        subs.map(sub => sub[initial]),
        state => state.some((substate, i) => subs[i][accept](substate)),
        state => char => state.map((substate, i) => subs[i][next](substate)(char)),
      ],
      // concat
      ([a, b]) => [
        [a[initial], a[accept](a[initial]) ? [b[initial]] : []],
        state => state[1].some(x => b[accept](x)),
        state => char =>
          [
            x = a[next](state[0])(char),
            set([
              ...a[accept](x) ? [b[initial]] : [],
              ...state[1].map(substate => b[next](substate)(char))
            ])
          ]
      ],
      // group
      _ => [
        0,
        state => state === 1,
        state => char => [re[1].includes(char) ? 1 : 2, 2, 2][state],
      ]
    ][re[0]](re[1].map(regexToDfa))
)(regex)

const testDfa = i => dfa[accept]([...i].reduce((a, b) => dfa[next](a)(b), dfa[initial]))

const invertDfa = dfa => [dfa[initial], x => !dfa[accept](x), dfa[next]]

const dfaToString = (dfa, paths = { s: { [str(dfa[initial])]: "" } }) =>
(
  (visitState = (state) => paths[x = str(state)] = paths[x] || (paths[x] = {},
    charset.reduce((obj, char, nextState) => (
      nextState = dfa[next](state)(char),
      visitState(nextState),
      obj[x = str(nextState)] = (obj[x] || "[]").slice(0, -1) + (char == "\\" || char == "]" ? "\\" : "") + char + "]",
      dfa[accept](state) && (obj.e = ""),
      obj
    ), {})
  ))(dfa[initial]),
  Object.keys(paths).map(removeState => removeState != "s" && (
    obj = paths[removeState],
    selfPath = obj[removeState],
    delete obj[removeState],
    delete paths[removeState],
    Object.keys(paths).map(a => (
      initialPath = paths[a][removeState]) !== {}.x &&
      delete paths[a][removeState] &&
      Object.keys(obj).map(b => (
        path = initialPath + (selfPath ? `(${selfPath})*` : "") + obj[b],
        paths[a][b] = paths[a][b] != {}.x ? `(${paths[a][b]}|${path})` : path
      ))
    )
  )),
  paths.s.e || "[]"
)

console.log(`^${dfaToString(invertDfa(dfa))}$`)
```

### Explanation

The program executes the following process:

1. Parse the regex into a tree structure
2. Convert the tree structure into a DFA
3. Invert the accepted/rejected states of the DFA
4. Convert the DFA into a (stringified) regex

In the parsed regex tree, the leaves are characters, and the branches are
operations. For example, `^a[bc](d|e*)$` would look like

```js
[2 /* concat */, [
  [2 /* concat */, [
    "a",
    [3 /* character group */, [
      "b",
      "c",
    ]],
  ]],
  [1 /* union */, [
    "d",
    [0 /* star */, [
      "e",
    ]],
  ]],
]]
```

A DFA is represented as a 3-tuple:

```js
[
  initial /* state */,
  accept /* state => bool */,
  next /* state => char => bool */,
]
```

States are numbers or deep arrays of numbers.

To convert this parsed regex into a DFA, the tree is processed bottom-up. Single
characters and character groups become 3-state DFAs (start, accept, and dead).
Operations compose their DFA operands in various ways; for example, union tracks
the state of each operand, and accepts any state where one of the operands is
accepting.

The DFA is then inverted by negating the `accept` function.

To convert the inverted DFA into a regex, it is encoded into a JS object that
represents a `(state, state) -> string`. Each string will be a regex that
accepts the set of strings that will move the DFA from one state to another.
Initially, the strings are simply character classes containing all of the
characters between the two states in the DFA. This is what the object would
look like initially for the regex `^[ab]$`, if the alphabet was limited to
`abc`.

```js
{
  s: { 0: "" },
  0: { 1: "[ab]", 2: "[c]" },
  1: { e: "", 2: "[abc]" },
  2: { 2: "[abc]" },
}
```

The special keys `s` and `e` represent the start and end, respectively. In this
case, the state `2` is a dead state, where no progress can be made. The leaf
values are referred to "arrows"; for example, the `01` arrow goes from `0` to
`1` and has a regex of `[ab]`. Any non-existent arrows have a regex of `[]`, a
regex that matches nothing.

This object now needs to be distilled to a singular regex. Then, each of the
states is removed iteratively. When removing states, the arrows associated with
those states must be combined with the other regexes.

If there are states `A` and `B` (not necessarily distinct), and a state `X` which is
being removed, arrow `AB` will be upserted to be

```
<AB>|<AX><XX>*<XB>
```

Note that:

- If there is no `XX` arrow, the `AB` arrow will become `<AB>|<AX><XB>`,
  as `[]*` is equivalent to `()` (the regex that matches the empty string).
- If there is no `AB` arrow, there will be a new arrow that is
  `<AX><XX>*<XB>`.
- If there is no `AX` arrow or no `XB` arrow, the `AB` arrow will
  be unchanged.

Thus, the object evolves as follows:

```js
// Original
{
  s: { 0: "" },
  0: { 1: "[ab]", 2: "[c]" },
  1: { e: "", 2: "[abc]" },
  2: { 2: "[abc]" },
}

// After removing 0
{
  s: { 1: "[ab]", 2: "[c]" },
  1: { e: "", 2: "[abc]" },
  2: { 2: "[abc]" },
}

// After removing 0 and 1
{
  s: { e: "[ab]", 2: "[c]|[ab][abc]" },
  2: { 2: "[abc]" },
}

// Final
{
  s: { e: "[ab]" },
}
```

In the end, the object will be `{ s: { e: <regex> } }` or `{ s: {} }`. If it's
the latter, there was no path from `s` to `e`, so the final regex is `[]`.

Interestingly, this process is far from lossless; running a regex through
without inverting it often still explodes the size:

```
Input: ^a[bc](d|e*)$
Output (not inverted): ^((([a][bc]|[a][bc][d])|[a][bc][e])|[a][bc][e][e]([e])*)$
```